# HTTP Network error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails, i have been building simple rails apps, trying to see how things work, of recent, each time i try **bundle install** if gives me the error below:

```
$ bundle install --without production

Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.Retrying dependency api due to error 
(2/4):Bundler::HTTPError Network error while fetching 
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?
gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffe e-rails%2Cjquery-
rails%2Cturbolinks%2Cjbuilder%2Csdoc%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data

Retrying dependency api due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Network error while 
fetching http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies? 
gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffee-rails%2Cjquery-rails%2Cturbolinks%
2Cjbuilder%2Csdoc%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data Retrying dependency api due to error 
(4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Network error while fetching http://bundler.rubygems.org/                                                                       
api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffee-rails
%2Cjquery-rails%2Cturbolinks%2Cjbuilder%2Csdoc%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch    
specs from http://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch
specs from http://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch
specs from http://rubygems.org/

Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/
```

I have an active internet connection so that i think is not the problem.
I have also checked `https://status.rubygems.org/` and it shows **all systems is operational**.
I have been battling with this problem for more than a week now trying to fix the problem with the help of online resource, but to no avail, please any one should help me it's really frustrating.

Comment: What version of Bundler are you running? You can find out by running `bundle version`.

Comment: it's Bundler version 1.11.2 @coreyward

Comment: You might want to update and see if that helps. There's a new indexing system, and anecdotally it now tries to use HTTPS more. `gem install bundler` should do the trick.

Comment: your the best thanks a lot sir, it's now working @coreyward